# KDE Neon Display-setup-script Nvidia Driver alternative

Tags: kde, nvidia, amd, kde5, kde-neon

I'm using KDE Neon based on Ubuntu 20.04 latest release version with last KDE on a Asus laptop with AMD Ryzen 4800H and Nvidia RTX 2060.

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers using ubuntu-drivers command in order to install nvidia-drivers-470.

I have already changed Systemd Target (similar to Runtime Level) to multi-user.target in order to prevent X from running an other OpenGL applications.

After that, I blacklisted Nouveau module from kernel and updated init-ramfs.

I'm finally trying to configure my display manager (KDE) from a script, which I have already written, called optimus.sh inside **/usr/local/bin**

optimus.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

On Lightdm I would be editing /etc/lightdm.conf directly to change the following line:

```
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/optimus.sh
```

However, there is no equivalent to lightdm.conf on KDE.

Do you know if there is a different way to achieve this step?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

You need to add this to the following file: `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` This will run the lines when SDDM starts. If the `Xsetup` file is not there,  you can create it.

I hope this helps.